# How to make api request for each data i have splited in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to make an api request for each data i have splited from the text area,
when one data have done it will continue to the next data

each data splited will we request respond from `api.php?email=data`
how to make it,so each data i have splited will be request respond from `api.php?email=`

here's the soucecode,but it's allways request respond for all splited data in one time.

can someone tell me please?
javascript code :

```
$(function() {
console['log']('%cdomain.com', 'background: black; color: red; font-size: x-large');
var _0xe4e8x1, _0xe4e8x2, _0xe4e8x3, _0xe4e8x4, _0xe4e8x5;
$('#start-button')['click'](function() {
    vaa = $('#empass')['val']();
    vaa = vaa['split']('\x0A');
    var _0xe4e8x6 = 0;
    $['each'](vaa, function(_0xe4e8x7, _0xe4e8x8) {
        _0xe4e8x5 = $['ajax']({
            type: 'GET',
            email: _0xe4e8x8,
            url: 'api.php?email=' + _0xe4e8x8,
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function(_0xe4e8x9) {
                $('#proc-send')['css']('display', 'block');
                $('#proc-done')['css']('display', 'none');
                $('#result-container')['css']({
                    display: 'flex'
                });
                $('#ygdicek')['html']('Checking <span id=counter>' + vaa['length'] + '</span> account');
                $('#empass')['attr']('disabled', true);
                $('#empass')['css']({
                    opacity: '0.5'
                });
            },
            success: function(_0xe4e8x9) {},
            error: function(_0xe4e8x9) {
                var _0xe4e8xa = document['getElementById']('unknown_res');
                _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] = _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] + '<span class=unk_reslt>' + _0xe4e8x8 + '<br></span>';
            },
            complete: function(_0xe4e8x9) {
                var _0xe4e8xb = _0xe4e8x9['responseJSON'];
                console['log'](_0xe4e8xb);
                if (_0xe4e8xb['status'] == 'live') {
                    $('#result-container')['css']({
                        background: ''
                    });
                    var _0xe4e8xc = _0xe4e8xb['country_code'];
                    _0xe4e8xc = _0xe4e8xc['toLowerCase']();
                    var _0xe4e8xd = '<i class=\'flag-icon flag-icon-' + _0xe4e8xc + '\'></i>';
                    var _0xe4e8xe = _0xe4e8xd + ' [' + _0xe4e8xb['country'] + '] ' + _0xe4e8xb['email'];
                    var _0xe4e8xa = document['getElementById']('live_res');
                    _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] = _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] + '<span class=live_reslt>' + _0xe4e8xe + '<br></span>';
                } else {
                    if (_0xe4e8xb['status'] == 'limited') {
                        $('#result-container')['css']({
                            background: ''
                        });
                        var _0xe4e8xc = _0xe4e8xb['country_code'];
                        _0xe4e8xc = _0xe4e8xc['toLowerCase']();
                        var _0xe4e8xd = '<i class=\'flag-icon flag-icon-' + _0xe4e8xc + '\'></i>';
                        var _0xe4e8xe = _0xe4e8xd + ' [' + _0xe4e8xb['country'] + '] ' + _0xe4e8xb['email'];
                        var _0xe4e8xa = document['getElementById']('limited_res');
                        _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] = _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] + '<span class=lim_reslt>' + _0xe4e8xe + '<br></span>';
                    } else {
                        if (_0xe4e8xb['status'] == 'unknown') {
                            $('#result-container')['css']({
                                background: ''
                            });
                            var _0xe4e8xe = _0xe4e8xb['email'];
                            var _0xe4e8xa = document['getElementById']('unknown_res');
                            _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] = _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] + '<span class=unk_reslt>' + _0xe4e8xe + ' (' + _0xe4e8xb['msg'] + ')</span>';
                        } else {
                            if (_0xe4e8xb['status'] == 'invalid') {
                                $('#result-container')['css']({
                                    background: ''
                                });
                                var _0xe4e8xe = _0xe4e8xb['email'];
                                var _0xe4e8xa = document['getElementById']('invalid_res');
                                _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] = _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] + '<span class=inv_reslt>' + _0xe4e8xe + '<br></span>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#result-container')['css']({
                        background: 'none'
                    });
                    clearTimeout();
                }, 300);
                var _0xe4e8x1 = $('.live_reslt')['length'];
                var _0xe4e8x2 = $('.lim_reslt')['length'];
                var _0xe4e8x3 = $('.unk_reslt')['length'];
                var _0xe4e8x4 = $('.inv_reslt')['length'];
                $('#berapaLive')['html'](_0xe4e8x1);
                $('#berapaLimited')['html'](_0xe4e8x2);
                $('#berapaUnknown')['html'](_0xe4e8x3);
                $('#berapaInvalid')['html'](_0xe4e8x4);
                var _0xe4e8xf = vaa['length']--;
                _0xe4e8xf = _0xe4e8xf - 1;
                $('#counter')['html'](_0xe4e8xf);
            }
        })
    });
});
$('#stop-button')['click'](function() {
    var _0xe4e8x10 = $('#empass')['val']()['split']('\x0A');
    var _0xe4e8x11 = 0;
    for (_0xe4e8x11 = 0; _0xe4e8x11 < _0xe4e8x10['length']; _0xe4e8x11++) {
        _0xe4e8x5['abort']()
    };
});
$(document)['ajaxStop'](function() {
    $('#proc-send')['css']('display', 'none');
    vaa = $('#empass')['val']();
    vaa = vaa['split']('\x0A');
    var _0xe4e8x1 = $('.live_reslt')['length'];
    var _0xe4e8x2 = $('.lim_reslt')['length'];
    var _0xe4e8x3 = $('.unk_reslt')['length'];
    var _0xe4e8x4 = $('.inv_reslt')['length'];
    var _0xe4e8x12 = 'Total Checked: ' + vaa['length'] + ' | ' + 'Live: ' + _0xe4e8x1 + ' | ' + 'Limited: ' + _0xe4e8x2 + ' | ' + 'Invalid: ' + _0xe4e8x4 + ' | ' + 'Unknown: ' + _0xe4e8x3;
    console['log'](_0xe4e8x12);
    $('#proc-done')['css']('display', 'block');
    $('#log_mess')['html'](_0xe4e8x12);
    $('#empass')['css']({
        opacity: '1'
    });
    $('#empass')['attr']('disabled', false);
});
```

});

Comment: Please point out a __PHP__ code here!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rUdsc78d

Comment: it's the php source code